# 5 columns with responsive images dont span inside main column row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have five col-md-2 and within each column there is a responsive image. These five columns are nested within a col-md-12, however each col-md-2 is not the default 230px width which makes all col-md-2 columns not span the entire col-md-12. I know that I should have 6 col-md-2 to fit the col-md-12, but why are my col-md-2 not the default 230px width wide, is it because of the img-responsive class?

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
         <div class="col-md-2"><img src="img1.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
         <div class="col-md-2"><img src="img1.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
         <div class="col-md-2"><img src="img1.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
         <div class="col-md-2"><img src="img1.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
         <div class="col-md-2"><img src="img1.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

thank you.

Comment: Can you please add a fiddle for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
.col-xs-5ths,
.col-sm-5ths,
.col-md-5ths,
.col-lg-5ths {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.col-xs-5ths {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}
img{
  max-width:100%;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.col-sm-5ths {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-md-5ths {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .col-lg-5ths {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** Modify media query css as per your need

Comment: do you know why the columns are not spreading the width of the col-md-12, though? Is it because of the responsive images?